# Using jsx command-line compiler -- won't compile to file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have what is probably a simple jsx question, so please forgive my stupidity.

I'm playing with React's jsx command-line compiler. I have a VERY simple JSX file that looks like this:

```
var helloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>hello</div>
    }
})
```

If I type the following in the command-line, it compiles (and shows me the result in the console): `jsx test.jsx`

I want to output this file to `test.js`. But if I try the command `jsx test.jsx test.js` nothing happens -- it only outputs the help information for the `jsx` command.

Any ideas? I feel like it should be obvious.

Comment: Tangentially related, `jsx -w -x jsx src/ build/` to watch `jsx` files that are in the src directory, and output them to the build directory.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, silly mistake. This command solves it:

`jsx test.jsx > test.js`. The `>` puts the output into a file. Simple enough.